# Python - sorted list of lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

Hi all
I am probably missing something obvious

Creating list of lists (in C++ notation "vector\\>"), then trying to sort inner lists ("records") using some of the fields as a sort keys. And it would not work. Tryed two different version: with "lambda" and with "itemgetter". There is no error or warning. What am I doing wrong?

//******** my code: start

class fwReport:

```
def __init__(self):
    #each field from firewall log file, 17 all together
    self.fieldnames = ("date", "time", "action", "protocol", \
              "src-ip", "dst-ip", "src-port", "dst-port" \
              "size", "tcpflags", "tcpsyn", "tcpack", \
              "tcpwin", "icmptype", "icmpcode", "info", "path")
    self._fields = {}
    self.mx = list()
    self.dst_ip = collections.Counter()
    self.src_ip = collections.Counter()

def openfn(self):
    try:
        with open(fn) as f: data = f.read()
    except IOError as err:
        raise AssertionError("Can't open %s for reading: %s" % (fn, err))
        return
    #make a matrix out of data, smth. like list<list<field>>
    #skip first 5 lines (file header)
    for fields in data.split("\n")[5:25]:
        temp = fields.split(" ")[:6] #take first 7 fields
        self.src_ip[temp[4]] += 1 #count source IP
        self.dst_ip[temp[5]] += 1 #count destination IP
        self.mx.append(temp) #build list of lists
    #sorted(self.mx, key=itemgetter(5)) #----> does not work
    sorted(self.mx, key=lambda fields: fields[5]) #--------> does not work
    for i in range(len(self.mx)):
        print(i, " ", self.mx[i][5])
    #print(self.dst_ip.most_common(16))
    #print(self.src_ip.most_common(16))
    print(self.mx[:5][:])
    #print(len(self.dst_ip))
```

## ***************

def main():

```
mx = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "c", "b"], ["b", "a", "c"]]

mx = sorted(mx, key=lambda v: v[1])

for i in range(len(mx)):
    print(i, " ", mx[i], " ", mx[i], end="\n")
```

0   ['b', 'a', 'c']   ['b', 'a', 'c']

1   ['a', 'b', 'c']   ['a', 'b', 'c']

2   ['a', 'c', 'b']   ['a', 'c', 'b']

## ****

Working fine.

@Ned Batchelder - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sorted` returns the new sorted list.  You aren't assigning the value to anything. Try:

```
self.mx = sorted(self.mx, key=itemgetter(5))
```

Comment: You still can sort in-place: `self.mx.sort(key=...)`

Comment: @9000 Thanks, both in-place and sorted(..) are working now. I've probably had a mental block. Till the next time...